# lazy scroll till the page ends, then show next page

Tags: django, django-endless-pagination

I'm using django-endless-pagination to load my objects on display. It works fine, but I want to load some pages on scrolling, then after these pages, I want to have a 'show more' which when clicked loads the next set of pages (again as we scroll)

If I use

```
<script>$.endlessPaginate();</script>
```

and

```
{% lazy_paginate 100 entries %}
```

I was hoping that these entries would load lazily, but they are not, they just load all 100 at a time. Also, i cant use something like

```
<script>
    $.endlessPaginate({
        paginateOnScroll: true,
        paginateOnScrollMargin: 20
    });  </script>
```

as this would load all the pages on scrolling, and not a set of pages.

This is what I want to do : http://www.flipkart.com/mens-clothing/trousers/pr?sid=2oq%2Cs9b%2C9uj&otracker=hp_submenu_clothing_Trousers&_pop=flyout
Here, each page gets loaded as we scroll, and after 20 pages, there is a 'show more pages', which loads page 21 and other pages on scrolling, and so on.

Any help on this would be great! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you use `{% lazy_paginate 100 entries %}` the behavior you get is correct: you are asking for 100 entries on each page.

Read the documentation here: http://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org/en/latest/templatetags_reference.html#paginate

As for the second part: yes, you can display a "show more" link after a certain number of pages:
http://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org/en/latest/javascript.html#on-scroll-pagination-using-chunks

Moreover, you might want to write the js call with

```js
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $.endlessPaginate();
   });
```